# Generic conversion of number arrays into bytes and vice-versa in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, byte, endianness

I have the following C# code to convert my number array into byte array and then save it as a base64 string and vice-versa, however it doesn't work for *long* because *long* is 8-byte and my code only works for 4-byte numbers.

```
private static int _endianDiff1;
private static int _endianDiff2;
private static int _idx;
private static byte[] _byteBlock;

enum ArrayType { Float, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64 }

public static bool SetIntArray(string key, int[] intArray)
{
    return SetValue(key, intArray, ArrayType.Int32, 1, ConvertFromInt);
}

public static bool SetLongArray(string key, long[] longArray)
{
    return SetValue(key, longArray, ArrayType.Int64, 1, ConvertFromLong);
}

private static bool SetValue<T>(string key, T array, ArrayType arrayType, int vectorNumber, Action<T, byte[], int> convert) where T : IList
{
    var bytes = new byte[(4 * array.Count) * vectorNumber + 1];
    bytes[0] = Convert.ToByte(arrayType);    // Identifier
    Initialize();

    for (var i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
    {
        convert(array, bytes, i);
    }
    return SaveBytes(key, bytes);
}

private static void ConvertFromInt(int[] array, byte[] bytes, int i)
{
    ConvertInt32ToBytes(array[i], bytes);
}

private static void ConvertFromLong(long[] array, byte[] bytes, int i)
{
    ConvertInt64ToBytes(array[i], bytes);
}

public static int[] GetIntArray(string key)
{
    var intList = new List<int>();
    GetValue(key, intList, ArrayType.Int32, 1, ConvertToInt);
    return intList.ToArray();
}

public static long[] GetLongArray(string key)
{
    var longList = new List<long>();
    GetValue(key, longList, ArrayType.Int64, 1, ConvertToLong);
    return longList.ToArray();
}

private static void GetValue<T>(string key, T list, ArrayType arrayType, int vectorNumber, Action<T, byte[]> convert) where T : IList
{
    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(key))
        return;
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(PlayerPrefs.GetString(key));
    if ((bytes.Length - 1) % (vectorNumber * 4) != 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Corrupt preference file for " + key);
        return;
    }
    if ((ArrayType)bytes[0] != arrayType)
    {
        Debug.LogError(key + " is not a " + arrayType + " array");
        return;
    }
    Initialize();

    var end = (bytes.Length - 1) / (vectorNumber * 4);
    for (var i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        convert(list, bytes);
    }
}

private static void ConvertToInt(List<int> list, byte[] bytes)
{
    list.Add(ConvertBytesToInt32(bytes));
}

private static void ConvertToLong(List<long> list, byte[] bytes)
{
    list.Add(ConvertBytesToInt64(bytes));
}

private static void Initialize()
{
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        _endianDiff1 = 0;
        _endianDiff2 = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        _endianDiff1 = 3;
        _endianDiff2 = 1;
    }
    if (_byteBlock == null)
    {
        _byteBlock = new byte[4];
    }
    _idx = 1;
}

private static bool SaveBytes(string key, byte[] bytes)
{
    try
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(key, Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private static void ConvertInt32ToBytes(int i, byte[] bytes)
{
    _byteBlock = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
    ConvertTo4Bytes(bytes);
}

private static void ConvertInt64ToBytes(long i, byte[] bytes)
{
    _byteBlock = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
    ConvertTo8Bytes(bytes);
}

private static int ConvertBytesToInt32(byte[] bytes)
{
    ConvertFrom4Bytes(bytes);
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(_byteBlock, 0);
}

private static long ConvertBytesToInt64(byte[] bytes)
{
    ConvertFrom8Bytes(bytes);
    return BitConverter.ToInt64(_byteBlock, 0);
}

private static void ConvertTo4Bytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    bytes[_idx] = _byteBlock[_endianDiff1];
    bytes[_idx + 1] = _byteBlock[1 + _endianDiff2];
    bytes[_idx + 2] = _byteBlock[2 - _endianDiff2];
    bytes[_idx + 3] = _byteBlock[3 - _endianDiff1];
    _idx += 4;
}

private static void ConvertFrom4Bytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    _byteBlock[_endianDiff1] = bytes[_idx];
    _byteBlock[1 + _endianDiff2] = bytes[_idx + 1];
    _byteBlock[2 - _endianDiff2] = bytes[_idx + 2];
    _byteBlock[3 - _endianDiff1] = bytes[_idx + 3];
    _idx += 4;
}

private static void ConvertTo8Bytes(byte[] bytes)
{

}

private static void ConvertFrom8Bytes(byte[] bytes)
{

}
```

So far I have it working for *int*, *uint* and *float* because they are all 4-byte and my problem is to change my Initialize function so it works based on the passed type size.

I guess there should also be *ConvertTo8Bytes* and *ConvertFrom8Bytes* functions which I don't know how to make because I set the *_endianDiff* and *_byteBlock* for 4-byte only. I understand that _byteBlock should have dynamic size instead of 4 but I don't know what to do with endianness in this case.

On the side note, I have solved this problem by splitting the *long* into 2 *int*s and just storing them as two *int* arrays, but I'm allocating useless memory like this just because I'm not able to make this algorithm to work.

Comment: Take a gander at the [BitConverter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `string ConvertToBase64(IEnumerable<long> list) 
        {
            var bytes = list.Select(x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x)).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a lot of code if all you are doing is trying to get a Base64 representation of a numeric array. Am I missing the goal?

If all you want to do is get int or long arrays to and from base64 strings, try this:

```
    private static string ConvertArrayToBase64<T>(IList<T> array) where T : struct
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
        {
            int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
            var byteArray = new byte[array.Count * size];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(array.ToArray(), 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Only primitive types are supported.");
    }

    private static T[] ConvertBase64ToArray<T>(string base64String) where T : struct
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
        {
            var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            var array = new T[byteArray.Length / System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf<T>()];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArray, 0, array, 0, byteArray.Length);
            return array;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Only primitive types are supported.");
    }
```

There are a couple things to consider with this code though...

It does make a complete copy of the array, so if you are dealing with a large array or a performance sensitive operation, it may not be the best way.

This should work with any "primitive value type" arrays, which should include all the numeric types like int, long, uint, float, etc.

To demonstrate usage, see this example:

```
        var longArray = new long[] { 11111, 22222, 33333, 44444 };
        var intArray = new int[] { 55555, 66666, 77777, 88888};

        string base64longs = ConvertArrayToBase64(longArray);
        Console.WriteLine(base64longs);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ConvertBase64ToArray<long>(base64longs)));

        string base64ints = ConvertArrayToBase64(intArray);
        Console.WriteLine(base64ints);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ConvertBase64ToArray<int>(base64ints)));
```

What it does:

- Verifies that the array only has primitive types.
- Determines the size of the elements in the array to
  calculate the length of the byte array to allocate.
- It copies the array to the byte array.
- Returns the base64 representation.

The complementary function does the reverse.

Update: Here are the .NET 2.0 compatible versions...

```
    private static string ConvertArrayToBase64<T>(IList<T> array) where T : struct
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
        {
            int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
            var byteArray = new byte[array.Count * size];
            Buffer.BlockCopy((Array)array, 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Only primitive types are supported.");
    }

    private static T[] ConvertBase64ToArray<T>(string base64String) where T : struct
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
        {
            var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            var array = new T[byteArray.Length / System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArray, 0, array, 0, byteArray.Length);
            return array;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Only primitive types are supported.");
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile for me *The non-generic method 'Marshal.SizeOf(object)' cannot be used with type arguments*

Comment: You are using Marshal.SizeOf(object) or Marshal.SizeOf<T>()? The code example uses the latter and compiles and runs fine for me. They are different functions. One passes the type T as a generic type, the other passes an object to determine the type. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I used the code from the example. I'm stuck to .NET 2.0 because I use Unity.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps the generic overload wasn't introduced until later. Try this: System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))

Comment: I did go back and confirm...the generic version wasn't available until 4.5.1. But the alternate shown above should work.

Comment: Oh..just happened to think...no Linq in 2.0 either. Like stepping back to the stone age. Let me see if I can come up with an alternative.

Comment: I added 2.0 compatible versions. I tested them in VS2015 targeting the 2.0 Framework and they appear to be working with no compile errors.

Comment: Why does it only work with primitive types? What if I want to convert decimal type which is not primitive but is also a number?